# how to change color of icons in bootstrap components

Tags: vue.js, colors, icons, bootstrap-5

I have implemented a dark mode in my `Vue` project which I created with `Bootstrap 5.2`.

But I don't know how to change the color (it should be ***white***) of the following two `icons`:

This is from a `form-select`
[image]

This is from a `input type="time"`
[image]

How can I achieve that?

**Code**

```
<template>
  <input class="form-control" type="time" />
  <select class="form-select"></select>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: added a template. It's so short, I didn't know that it's relevant in this case..

Comment: Yes, it's relevant to repro the issue. How did you implement "dark mode" as this was not supported until [Bootstrap 5.3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/color-modes/)?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap 5.3 implements dark mode. If you upgrade to 5.3, the inputs carets will be light colored by simply using `<html data-bs-theme="dark">..`

[Demo - 5.3 dark mode inputs](https://codeply.com/p/W5RfpFIxq1)

If you want to use 5.2, you'll need to override the `form-select` class background image SVGs `stroke` color to change caret color...

```
.form-select {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23ffffff' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='m2 5 6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")
}
```

[Demo - 5.2 dark theme inputs](https://codeply.com/p/TK0s9MfMpv)

Comment: Hi, thank you! Is there a possibility to avoid using the link of w3, can I do it with my own image ?

Comment: That's just a namespace for the svg spec.. nothing to do with the svg image. Also, please answer the question about which version or how you created dark mode.